# Unity - 2D - Pixel Image distorted troubleshooting

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Novice Unity user. I want to create a pixel art 2D RPG game for fun in unity. I ran into an issue with my pixel art when I would drag it into the scene window. What would happen is that the Game Window would distort the pixel sizes to be either twice as wide or twice as narrow in the x and y direction. I have no clue on how to fix this issue and looked all over. I would appreciate any feedback. But I would prefer a discord call so that I may share my screen to get efficient troubleshooting advice! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few tutorials and even helper packages to deal with Pixel Art games in Unity:

- [Achieve Crisp Pixel Art with Unity 2018.2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CU4YjSZNTnY)
- [Pixel Perfect Package](https://forum.unity.com/threads/pixel-perfect-preview-package.533433/)
- [Making A Flappy Bird Style Game](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/live-session-making-a-flappy-bird-style-game#)

By default, Unity will import your images as Textures and resize them to the nearest Power of 2, which should explain the distortion observed.

---

A bit more advanced, but if you want all the images to import as Sprite, you can save a Sprite import setting as a preset and then assign it to the TextureImporter in Project Setting > Preset Manager. See [Reusing property settings](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Presets.html) and [Preset Manager](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PresetManager.html).

hth.